# Two-page sign-up process in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm attempting to create a rails app where a user will sign up, then immediately be directed to fill out a profile with more detailed information.

I'm currently attempting this by having both a `users` and a `profile` model, with a `has_one/belongs_to` relationship between the two models.

I'm having trouble with `create`ing the profile for the user. Tests fail with `undefined method`profiles' for #`when testing the creation, and using an automated profile builder called`sample_data.rake`:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task :populate => :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
    admin = User.create!(:name => "name name",
                 :email => "fakename@fake.com",
                 :password => "password",
                 :password_confirmation => "password")
    admin.toggle!(:admin)
    99.times do |n|
      name = Faker::Name.name
      email = Faker::Internet.email
      password = "password"
      User.create!(:name => name,
                   :email => email,
                   :password => password,
                   :password_confirmation => password)
    end

          User.all.each do |user|
            User.profiles.create(:city => Faker::Address.city,
                                 :state => Faker::Address.us_state_abbr,
                                 ...
                                 )
          end

  end
end
```

Also fails on 
I'm having trouble with `create`ing the profile for the user. Tests fail with `undefined method 'profiles'`

`profiles_controller.rb` is:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :edit]

  def create
    @profile = current_user.profiles.build(params[:profile])
        if @profile.save
          flash[:success] = "Profile Created!"
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render 'pages/home'
        end
  end

  def edit

  end

end
```

`profile.rb` is

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :state, ...
  belongs_to :user

  validates :city, :presence => true

  validates :state, :presence => true

  ...

end
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to merge all the items I need under "users", validate the presence of all the required information, and have the signup process be two pages?

Other suggestions for this?

Comment: Have you considered using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to do your signups and registrations?

Comment: No. And I won't. I'm using this as a learning experience. If I wanted things pre-done, I'd just pay someone on elance or something.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do this?
`1.times do...end`
You dont need that.

The failure comes up because you need to create ONE profile, not profiles, for one certain user.
So try this:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.create_profile(:city => "bla", ...)
end
```

In you controller the same. You have just one profile, using singular will help out.

Comment: Tried that. While that's cleaner code, it still fails with the same error above.

Comment: Rails does not give the Error undefined method profiles (plural) when you call profile (singular). Please take a look at my code above, I had a little mistake there. This should work correctly now.

Comment: Do you use exactly what i wrote above? I think you probably called the method `create_profile` on the `User` model, not on the instance `user`. (its case-sensitive)